# Which programming language which I need to learn to make a website as Avi Shivman

Tags: database, api, server

In Egypt, ninth grade is as important as twelfth grade,so results are displayed on our ministry of education server and it is a very bad server. If the result was announced at 8 p.m. all people want to know it at 8:10 PM server is not found.So, I need a way to grab results from that server before it is fallen and put it on my computer. I think that that server offers its data easily as many websites in Egypt do this. Can you please tell me the needed language 
I know that maybe a little bit opinion based question, but I want to know the easiest way or easiest programming language which may help.

Comment: You face the same challenge as everyone. You need to get a connection to an overloaded server that everyone else is trying to access. It's pot luck whether you get one. You can use something like `Curl.exe` to repeatedly make a web request and save the page locally but it depends on how the page is built

Comment: If I had a stable server which doesn't have all that number of visitors and I want to take information from that server which programming language should I learn

Comment: I already said you should look into `curl.exe`

Comment: The real solution is to use a load balancer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need an internet connection that's for everyone the same.
But what you could do is build a simple python bot to read the website or an API.
One option would be something like requests for a very simple website.
with a more complicated website you could use python and selenium, to also preform a LogIn.
But very important you wouldn't get a advantage if the connection is to slow, your only option is to be the fastest.

Comment: If I have that server to be not that crowded and it doesn't have all that visitors at the same time what should I learn to be able to grab data from that server. Sorry for interrupting you

Comment: You could use a few different languages but I personally would recommend Python. If you could provide the link of the address, I might be able to say more. But either way Python with requests or selenium sounds good.

Comment: A very good idea would be to learn the python basics and then use crawler

Comment: Thanks,dude.But should I learn python then django Thanks for your effort

Comment: Yes I would say start with the python basics and then learn requests and crawler. Django is not needed but you still can learn it. When this answers your question please mark it as solved.